# sql sentence to update domain name in a path's row

Tags: mysql, sql

lets say this table

```
+--------------+---------------------------------+
| id           | path                            |
+--------------+---------------------------------+
| 1            | http://old.com/img/1.png        | 
| 2            | http://old.com/img/2.png        | 
| 3            | http://old.com/img/3.png        | 
| 4            | http://old.com/img/4.png        | 
| 5            | http://old.com/img/5.png        | 
| 6            | http://old.com/img/6.png        | 
+--------------+---------------------------------+
```

what sentence will update it to

```
+--------------+---------------------------------+
| id           | path                            |
+--------------+---------------------------------+
| 1            | http://new.com/img/1.png        | 
| 2            | http://new.com/img/2.png        | 
| 3            | http://new.com/img/3.png        | 
| 4            | http://new.com/img/4.png        | 
| 5            | http://new.com/img/5.png        | 
| 6            | http://new.com/img/6.png        | 
+--------------+---------------------------------+
```

i don't know how to str_replace in mysql

`"UPDATE table SET path = REPLACE(path, 'old.com', 'new.com')"`  ?? i can't mess the database here..

Comment: Always always always always *always* always ALWAYS always back up first.

Comment: Your code looks right. If you want to check it, do a "SELECT path, REPLACE(path, 'old.com', 'new.com') FROM table" to see if the results look right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update mytable set path = replace(path, 'old.com', 'new.com');
```

If you're worried about the effect of an update (and you should be), I do this first:

```
select path, replace(path, 'old.com', 'new.com') as new_path
from mytable;
```

And I just eyeball the results to see if they "look OK". If they do, if fire the update.

Answer (score 0):

There is no regexp replace feature in mySQL proper: The regex functions are match only. Here is mysql [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)